# collapse a number of column IDs into a single ID column

Tags: r

I am trying to merge some data. I have some data which contains IDs. I want to merge each of the columns into a new column `finalID` which collapses all the other columns down into a single column.

For many of the column IDs they will be the same however one or two columns might be different. If they are different then I would like it such that it adds the second ID into a new column `finalID_WithDoubleResults` for example.

How can I first, collapse the columns into a single ID column
Then, if the columns contain different IDs Split them into two or more newer columns.

Data:

```
structure(list(sabiUniqueID.x = c(74L, 82L, 129L, 153L, 179L, 
203L, 211L, 220L, 223L, 231L, 237L, 243L, 259L, 260L, 275L, 280L, 
290L, 292L, 297L, 300L), sabiUniqueID.y = c(74L, 82L, 129L, NA, 
NA, NA, 211L, NA, 223L, 231L, 237L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 290L, 
NA, 297L, NA), sabiUniqueID.x.x = c(74L, 82L, 129L, 153L, NA, 
NA, 211L, NA, 223L, 231L, 237L, NA, NA, 260L, 275L, NA, 290L, 
292L, 297L, NA), sabiUniqueID.y.y = c(NA, NA, 129L, NA, 179L, 
203L, 211L, NA, 223L, NA, NA, NA, 259L, 260L, 275L, NA, 290L, 
292L, NA, NA), sabiUniqueID.x.x.x = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 292L, NA, NA), sabiUniqueID.y.y.y = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 260L, 275L, NA, 
290L, NA, NA, NA), sabiUniqueID.x.x.x.x = c(74L, 82L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 243L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 292L, NA, 
NA), sabiUniqueID.y.y.y.y = c(74L, 82L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 260L, 275L, NA, 290L, NA, NA, NA), sabiUniqueID.x.x.x.x.x = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 290L, 
NA, NA, 300L), sabiUniqueID.y.y.y.y.y = c(74L, 82L, 129L, NA, 
179L, 203L, NA, NA, 223L, NA, NA, 243L, NA, 260L, NA, NA, 290L, 
292L, NA, 300L), sabiUniqueID.x.x.x.x.x.x = c(74L, 82L, 129L, 
153L, 179L, 203L, 211L, 220L, 223L, 231L, 237L, 243L, 259L, 260L, 
275L, 280L, 290L, 292L, 297L, 300L), sabiUniqueID.y.y.y.y.y.y = c(NA, 
82L, NA, NA, 179L, 203L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 243L, 259L, 260L, 
NA, 280L, 290L, 292L, NA, 300L), sabiUniqueID = c(NA, 82L, NA, 
NA, 179L, 203L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 243L, 259L, 260L, NA, 280L, 
290L, 292L, NA, 300L)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), groups = structure(list(
    sabiUniqueID.x = c(74L, 82L, 129L, 153L, 179L, 203L, 211L, 
    220L, 223L, 231L, 237L, 243L, 259L, 260L, 275L, 280L, 290L, 
    292L, 297L, 300L), sabiUniqueID.y = c(74L, 82L, 129L, NA, 
    NA, NA, 211L, NA, 223L, 231L, 237L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 290L, 
    NA, 297L, NA), sabiUniqueID.x.x = c(74L, 82L, 129L, 153L, 
    NA, NA, 211L, NA, 223L, 231L, 237L, NA, NA, 260L, 275L, NA, 
    290L, 292L, 297L, NA), sabiUniqueID.y.y = c(NA, NA, 129L, 
    NA, 179L, 203L, 211L, NA, 223L, NA, NA, NA, 259L, 260L, 275L, 
    NA, 290L, 292L, NA, NA), sabiUniqueID.x.x.x = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 292L, 
    NA, NA), sabiUniqueID.y.y.y = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 260L, 275L, NA, 290L, NA, NA, NA), 
    sabiUniqueID.x.x.x.x = c(74L, 82L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 243L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 292L, NA, NA), sabiUniqueID.y.y.y.y = c(74L, 
    82L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 260L, 275L, 
    NA, 290L, NA, NA, NA), sabiUniqueID.x.x.x.x.x = c(NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 290L, 
    NA, NA, 300L), sabiUniqueID.y.y.y.y.y = c(74L, 82L, 129L, 
    NA, 179L, 203L, NA, NA, 223L, NA, NA, 243L, NA, 260L, NA, 
    NA, 290L, 292L, NA, 300L), sabiUniqueID.x.x.x.x.x.x = c(74L, 
    82L, 129L, 153L, 179L, 203L, 211L, 220L, 223L, 231L, 237L, 
    243L, 259L, 260L, 275L, 280L, 290L, 292L, 297L, 300L), sabiUniqueID.y.y.y.y.y.y = c(NA, 
    82L, NA, NA, 179L, 203L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 243L, 259L, 
    260L, NA, 280L, 290L, 292L, NA, 300L), .rows = structure(list(
        1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
        14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr"))), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

EDIT:

Smaller data

```
structure(list(sabiUniqueID.x = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 820L), sabiUniqueID.y = c(1301L, 
                                                                            NA, NA, NA, 820L), sabiUniqueID.x.x = c(9999L, NA, 1176L, NA, 
                                                                                                                    820L), sabiUniqueID.y.y = c(NA, NA, NA, 1537L, 820L), sabiUniqueID.x.x.x = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 NA, NA, NA, 820L)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Which looks like:

```
    sabiUniqueID.x sabiUniqueID.y sabiUniqueID.x.x sabiUniqueID.y.y sabiUniqueID.x.x.x
           <int>          <int>            <int>            <int>              <int>
1             NA           1301             9999               NA                 NA
2             NA             NA               NA               NA                 NA
3             NA             NA             1176               NA                 NA
4             NA             NA               NA             1537                 NA
5            820            820              820              820                820
```

Where now I have added the result `9999` and it has two IDs for this observation (the other observations have duplicated IDs).

So the expected output might look like:

```
finalID  finalID_WithDoubleResults
1301         99999
NA            NA
1176          NA
1537          NA
820           NA
```

EDIT2:

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(sabiUniqueID.x:sabiUniqueID.x.x.x), names_to = "id_type", values_to = "id_

value") %>% 
  group_by(id_type) %>% 
  arrange(desc(id_value)) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  #select(-c(id_type)) %>% 
  mutate(rowID = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = id_type, values_from = id_value)
```

Comment: I think this problem would be much more understandable and faster to answer if you reduced your data to say, 5 rows and 3 columns, and showed the expected output for your input. (With a note that the solution needs to easily generalize up to many columns.)

Comment: The data has 20 rows and 13 variables, is this too large? I will add an expected output now.

Comment: I like to make examples a small as possible while still communicating the complexity across. (**Minimal** reproducible example is the common term.) I find it much easier to understand what's going on when it takes < 10 seconds to trace the path between the input and the output - when possible.  20 rows * 13 variables = 260 values is a fair bit of data to inspect. 5 rows * 3 variables = 15 values is nice and small.

Comment: I see, that makes perfect sense, I added a smaller example.

Comment: But don't oversimplify. *"Where in this example there were no different IDs in the rows."* One of the reasons I asked for sample output is that I want to make sure I understand what you mean by *"if the columns contain different IDs Split them into two or more newer columns"*... how does the splitting work? What do you want the additional columns to be named? Which ID goes in the `finalID` column and which one goes in the others? An example would help clear that up.

Comment: I have modified the EDIT.

Comment: Great - much clearer. Question in row 1 of the output, why does `1301` go in the first column, and `99999` go in the second. For the `finalID` column do you want to pick the first value? Lowest value? Most common value? (If most common, what is the tie-breaker in this case where `1301` and `99999` each show up once?) Random value? Something else? (And does that generalize if there are more than 2 duplicates?)

Comment: Adding the most common value to the `finalID` column would be the best option. Then a random selection if there are equal number of occurances of the values. If there are more tan 2 duplicates (I dont expect this to be the case) but then I would créate a new column `finalID_WithTrippleResults`. The results which appear in `finalID_WithDoubleResults` and `finalID_WithTrippleResults` I will check manually so just having the most frequent result in the `finalID` column would be great, after that the order of the variables matter less.

Comment: Okay - that's good and clear. I don'thave time just now to write up an answer, but I'll try to circle back later today (unless someone else takes the initiative). But if you want to have a go, the general approach I'd take is (a) convert the data to long format with columns `original_row`, `id_type`, and `id_value`, (b) grouped by `original_row`, sort `id_value` by frequency, (c) remove duplicate `id_value`s (d) drop the `id_type` column and convert back to wide format.

Comment: I will give this a try, thanks!

Comment: I did the following but it doesn't quite get what I want. I think I am missing your `original_row` part. (I add the code to an EDIT2).

Comment: Make your first step adding an original row. `df %>% mutate(original_row = 1:n()) %>% ...`. (Normally I'd call it `ID`, but you've got plenty of those already!)